# fade in or out depending on active class, fade in works, out does not

Tags: javascript, css, animation

This is probably best viewed in the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h1bsnequ/12/).

This is a simple fade in/out slideshow for a portfolio. The displayed slide has a class "active". It should fade out before the next slide fades in. Instead it disappears instantly. The fade in of the next slide is working fine.

This is the basic html code.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("inner-portfolio-wrapper").childElementCount;
  var j = 1;
  var k;

  function clickMe() {
    if (x > 1) {
      if (j === x) {
        j = 1;
        k = x;
      } else {
        k = j;
        j++;
      }
      console.log("j = " + j);
      console.log("k = " + k);
      document.getElementById("portfolio-item-" + k).style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("portfolio-item-" + j).style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("portfolio-item-" + j).classList.add("active");
      document.getElementById("portfolio-item-" + k).classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
```

```css
#inner-portfolio-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}

.portfolio-item {
  display: none;
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
}

.portfolio-item .active {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeOut 2s;
}

.portfolio-item:first-child {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="inner-portfolio-wrapper">
  <div id="portfolio-item-1" class="portfolio-item">
    <h2>
      ITEM 1
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="portfolio-item-2" class="portfolio-item">
    <h2>
      ITEM 2
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="portfolio-item-3" class="portfolio-item">
    <h2>
      ITEM 3
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="clickMe()">
Click Me
</button>
```

Any help to get the fade out working would be appreciated. Everything else is working just fine.

Comment: there is a space in the CSS .. active is not linked with your element it should be `.portfolio-item.active`

Comment: You have to delay setting `display: none` until the animation has time to finish. Remove the active class, set a timeout for the animation duration, and then switch to display none when the timeout completes.

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah the space was not there originally, i added it while troubleshooting to no avail

Comment: @DanielBernardi ahh. I bet you're right. Unfortunately this is all running inside a larger setInterval function that won't let me do that. I may have to completely break it out of that.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `visibility: hidden; pointer-events: none;` to hide the element instead of `display: none`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, `fadeOut` animation doesn't work because click on button immediately removes `.active` from the item and it gets style `display: none`.

To get the desired effect the only thing your `onClick` function has to do - is to trigger `fadeOut` animation. All next actions have to be called as callback of  `animationEnd` event.

You also need to make some changes in styles:

```
.portfolio-item {
   display: none;
}

.portfolio-item.active {
   display: block;
   animation: fadeIn 2s;
}

.portfolio-item.active.out {
   display: block;
   animation: fadeOut 2s;
}
```

And finally, it works:

```js
//detect the supported event property name and assign it to variable
// Function from David Walsh: http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback
function whichAnimationEvent() {
  var t,
    el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

  var animations = {
    "animation": "animationend",
    "OAnimation": "oAnimationEnd",
    "MozAnimation": "animationend",
    "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
  }

  for (t in animations) {
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
      return animations[t];
    }
  }
}

var animationEvent = whichAnimationEvent();
//Declare global variables
var total = document.getElementById("inner-portfolio-wrapper").childElementCount;
var currentNum = 1
var nextNum;
//Get all portfolio items add add them an event listener
var items = document.getElementById("inner-portfolio-wrapper").children
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener(animationEvent, function(e) {
    if (e.animationName === 'fadeOut') {
      this.classList.toggle('out')
      this.classList.toggle('active');
      document.getElementById("portfolio-item-" + nextNum).classList.toggle('active')
      currentNum = nextNum
    }
  })
}
//When page loaded make first porfolio item active
items[0].classList.add("active");

function clickMe() {
  if (total > 1) {
    var currentElement = document.getElementById("portfolio-item-" + currentNum);
    nextNum = (currentNum === total) ? 1 : currentNum + 1
    currentElement.classList.toggle('out')
  }
}
```

```css
#inner-portfolio-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}

.portfolio-item {
  display: none;
}

.portfolio-item.active {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
}

.portfolio-item.active.out {
  display: block;
  animation: fadeOut 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="inner-portfolio-wrapper">
  <div id="portfolio-item-1" class="portfolio-item">
    <h2>
      ITEM 1
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="portfolio-item-2" class="portfolio-item">
    <h2>
      ITEM 2
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="portfolio-item-3" class="portfolio-item">
    <h2>
      ITEM 3
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="clickMe()">
Click Me
</button>
```